# Link from a Fiori application to a normal web application

Tags: sap-fiori

It's not a programming question but much more of a concept question.
I have a web application which was built using HTML and JS on the front-side and using Spring MVC on the back-end.
And I want to create a dashboard which can give me a lot of KPI data in a panel just like Fiori menu has.

What I'd like to do is to create those dashboard using Fiori, and when I click on the Fiori panel, it would move me into my web application HTML page.

Is it possible to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yess, you can open any url from a Fiori App or dashboard. You can even create iFrame Integration (if your “other” app will allow it).

You may have deeper integration (since Fiori is also a web app in the end), but that would require deep understanding of both. And may (most probably will) require mods on both apps

Comment: hi there, thank you very much for your reply. I've done some research also on my end, and found that I can use SAP UI5 if I only want to use the UI part of Fiori into my web system. and after following some tutorial about how to insert SAP UI 5 sdk into eclipse I can create new Fiori like HTML page on eclipse. but, I still can't insert those HTML page into my web project and can't find any tutorial for that. do you have any experience for this or maybe any tutorial that I can refer to?